# How to obtain all the Google Hangouts a user has participated in?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

The Google Hangout APIs do not seem to have the ability to fetch all Hangouts for a user. Also, the Google plus APIs to not seem to have Hangouts as part of activities or moments. Are there any Google APIs that return the past Hangout list to use along with the Google Hangout APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not any public Google APIs to get a list of Video Hangouts a user has participated in. You can [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) if you would like to see such an API method.